# Parse array of logical strings into another human readable object

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to parse an array into logical structure using recursive function and so far, only close encounters.

This is what i receive:

```
[
 "1921",
 "AND",
 "(",
 "1923",
 "OR",
 "(",
 "1925",
 "AND",
 "1924",
 ")",
 ")"
]
```

And this is what i must obtain:

```
{
 terms: ["1921", {
  terms: ["1923", {
   terms: ["1925", "1924"],
   operator: "AND"
  }],
  operator: "OR"
 }],
 operator: "AND"
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd approach it as a state machine which stores the current index and recursively iterates over the array item by item.

```
class StateMachine {
    protected $index = 0;
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getTree() {
        return $this->parse($this->data);
    }

    protected function parse() {
        $result = ["terms" => []];
        while ($this->index < count($this->data)) {
            switch($this->data[$this->index]) { 
                case "(": 
                    $this->index++;
                    $result["terms"][] = $this->parse();
                    break;
                case ")":
                    $this->index++;
                    return $result;
                    break;
                case "AND":
                    $result["operator"] = "AND";
                    $this->index++;
                    break;
                case "OR":
                    $result["operator"] = "OR";
                    $this->index++;
                    break;
                default:
                    $result["terms"][] = $this->data[$this->index];
                    $this->index++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$array = [
    "1921",
    "AND",
    "(",
    "1923",
    "OR",
    "(",
    "1925",
    "AND",
    "1924",
    ")",
    ")"
];

$machine = new StateMachine($array);
print json_encode($machine->getTree());
```

And you'll get exactly what you need.

Rewriting this to a recursive function would require using a global variable, but the principle will be similar.

Comment: Thank you sir! That really helped and this way i saw where i was having issues.